# Laravel Multi Auth before not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using ollieread multiauth. I got the problem when at route i try to use

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function()
{
Route::get('/onlinetest', array('as'=>'onlinetest', 'uses'=>'HomeController@onlinetest'));
Route::get('/quiz', array( 'as'=>'quiz', 'uses'=>'HomeController@quiz'));
Route::get('/number', array( 'as'=>'number', 'uses'=>'HomeController@number'));
Route::get('/word', array( 'as'=>'word', 'uses'=>'HomeController@word'));

});
```

Here is my usercontroller:

```
public function handlelogin()
{
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $userdata = array( 
        'email' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );


    if (Auth::check()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    if(Auth::user()->attempt($userdata, true))
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->get()->id);

        // check if user has use his account for test
        if ($user->status == '0') 
        {
            Auth::logout();
            Session::flush();
            return Redirect::to('/login')->with('message', FlashMessage::DisplayAlert('Your Account has been used for test', 'warning'));
        }

        $datebirth = Date($user->BirthDate);
        $dob = Date("Y") - $datebirth;

        Session::put('current_user', Input::get('username'));
        Session::put('full_name', $user->FullName);
        Session::put('gender', $user->Sex);
        Session::put('dob', $dob);
        Session::put('user_id', $user->id);

        // set the user last login
        $user->last_login = $today;
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::to('/onlinetest')->with('message', 'Login Successfully.');

    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/login')->with('message', FlashMessage::DisplayAlert('Incorrect Username / Password', 'danger'));
    }
}
```

My Filter:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application & Route Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Below you will find the "before" and "after" events for the application
| which may be used to do any work before or after a request into your
| application. Here you may also register your custom route filters.
|
*/

App::before(function($request)
{
    //
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Guest Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The "guest" filter is the counterpart of the authentication filters as
| it simply checks that the current user is not logged in. A redirect
| response will be issued if they are, which you may freely change.
|
*/

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CSRF Protection Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The CSRF filter is responsible for protecting your application against
| cross-site request forgery attacks. If this special token in a user
| session does not match the one given in this request, we'll bail.
|
*/

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() !== Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

apparently if I not using olliread this route is not working. I always can go to onlinetest even i'm not logging in.
Is there any solution for the route? or maybe I got it wrong at my controller?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code of your "user" filter? The default filter for authorisation is named "Auth".

Comment: try put this in your user controller if not there  "public function __construct(){
$this->beforeFilter('auth');
}"

Comment: i've tried. its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "user" filter which you specify in your Route group. Try swapping out "user" in your route group to "auth":

```
<?php
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function()
{
    // ...
});
```

Comment: i change user to auth. but i still can get into quiz without login. (i've tried to logout and close the browser too).